# MongoDB - Preserve order when using sample

Tags: mongodb

I want to have pagination and sampling.

I have a client that requests entities in a random order.
I want to implement a new feature - pagination.
The only way I can think of is to use match to ensure the entities to be served do not have ID's of the entities already served, but this sounds like an expensive operation.

Is there a way to randomise the order of entities in a collection, and save it in a way? So that I can use skip on it?

Comment: Randomized order of the results and pagination? It's sounds a bit illogical.

Comment: @Neodan perhaps a temporary index that retains the order?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a combination of [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) and [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)?

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $sample: { size: 300 } // get 300 random documents
}, {
    $out: "temp" // write results to a new "temp" collection
})
```

Comment: the issue is that the set of documents serve would be unique to each client. I think creating a collection each time would be an expensive operation.

I think the state should be stored on the client's side, and not on the server's side. So what I have resorted to is to have an array of ID's of the documents that the client has already received, then to use $nin to ensure the subsquent pages are not serving documents with IDs in that array.